# Agressive template caching in EE1

Tags: templates, ee1, embeds, caching

I've got an old EE1 site that I'm doing some minor updates to but I'm finding that it is very aggressively caching embedded templates.

This means that when I make a change it doesn't appear on the site until I clear the Template (page) Cache in the control panel.

Is there a setting somewhere to restrict this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like some of those templates have cache enabled? Did you check the template preferences?

Go to **Templates > Choose Template Group > Click Preferences > Here you can adjust template settings**

Comment: Yep, that looks like the issue. Caching was turned on for the embedded navigation template. Thank you.